# The divisor of a nonconstant function on a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C/K$ be a smooth curve and $f \in K(C)$ be a function. Then by identifying $f$ with a rational map, we can get a 1-1 correspondence with maps $C \to \mathbf{P}^1$, with one direction being given by $P \mapsto [f(P),1]$.

> In the situation as above, 
>   $$ \textrm{div} (f) = f^* ((0) - (\infty))$$

This is supposed to follow directly from the definitions. On the one hand, I know that

$$ \textrm{div} (f) = \sum_{P \in C} v_P (f) (P) $$

For the right hand side,

$$ f^* ((0) - (\infty)) = f^* ((0)) - f^* (( \infty ))$$
At this point, I can intuitively see the result: we count the zeros with multiplicities and the poles with multiplicities and those are all the nonzero divisors of $f$. However, I would like to see a rigorous proof involving the definitions, valuations, etc.

Comment: Well it seems that everything follows from the definition of pullback: what is $f^*((0))$? A more exotic interpretation can be to note that $f^*((0))=0\times_{\mathbb{P}^1}C$ which can be computed as the subscheme of the zeros of $f$ (counted with multiplicities), but this makes probably things more difficult than what they are..

Comment: By definition then, $f*((0)) = \sum_{f(P) = 0} v_P (t) (P)$ where $t \in \mathcal{O}_0$ is a local parameter at $0$. I guess my problem is I'm not sure how to handle $t$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure about your doubts: $f$ is given. Do you have problems in computing $v_P(f)$? Have you tried with an explicit example?

Comment: I asked about computing the local parameter.

Comment: Take $ C=\mathbb {A}^1$ and $ f (x)=x^2/(x-1) $. The local ring in $0$ is $\mathbb {C}[x]_{(x)} $ and $ f $ can be written as the product of an invertible element, i.e. $ (x-1)$, and an element in the maximal ideal, i.e. $ x^2$: by definition $ v_0 (f)=2$ (the exponent of $ x $, the generator of the maximal ideal). If you carry on the same argument with $1$ instead of $0$, then you will get $ v_1 (f)=-1$. Now, $ div (f)=2 (0) -1 (1) $ and $ f^*((0))=2 (0) $ and $ f^*((\infty))=-1 (1) $.